# The product of two functions in Campanato space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

I've been wondering whether the Campanato space over $(-\delta, \delta)$ (let's denote it $X$)
 is closed under multiplication or not. In the case of $\lambda = 1$, I quite easily observed it is not (I proved $\log|x|$ and $\chi_{(0, \delta)}$ is in $X$ but $\chi_{(0, \delta)}\cdot \log|x|$ is not). However, I struggle to modify it for the case of $\lambda\in[0, 1)$. I expect it is not closed under multiplication for those $\lambda$ as well but I haven't been able to prove it.

I'll be really greateful for any hints.
Thank you!